# HtmlAgilityPack Error Handling - catching exception

Tags: c#, error-handling, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to determine how to catch the exception what i am getting is `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

is there any better way to catch the exception and showed to the user cause of the exception?

```
       baseUrl = "my url....";
        try
        {
            HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument docSRC = hw.Load(baseUrl);

            //if (docSRC.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img/@src").Count > 0)
            //{

            //}

            foreach (HtmlNode link in docSRC.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img/@src"))
            {
                HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["src"];
                srcTags.Add(att.Value);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //catch reason for exception....
        }
```

Comment: I wish HtmlAgilityPack would just return null if it cannot find an element. This would be way easier than pre checking if an element exists or throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any other way to handle exception. But it will be better if you can avoid the exception in the first place.

Looking at code snippet posted, `NullReferenceException` could be thrown when there is a `link` that doesn't have `src` attribute (this part `att.Value` will throw exception because `att` is `null` in this case).

You can use `GetAttributeValue()` method to avoid the exception, for example :

```
//here when the attribute not found, the 2nd parameter will be returned 
//(empty string in this case)
var src =  link.GetAttributeValue("src", "");
```

Comment: 1+ for giving me idea.... I'm getting the error on the foreach loop line `foreach (HtmlNode link in docSRC.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img/@src"))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I able to solve:

```
            if (docSRC.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img/@src") != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode link in docSRC.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img/@src"))
                {
                    HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["src"];
                    srcTags.Add(att.Value);

                }
            }
```

Hope this helps other folks!